# Python - trying to work out the correct loop in this method, it works util selecting the payment method, something wrong with the loop / checkout

Tags: python, loops

So I am trying to code a checkout function, this is how it looks, at the moment it doesn't work when selecting the payment method I think its the loop or that I have used checkout == twice in the function.

```
 def checkout(self):
      while True:
        if not shopping_cart:
            print("Your cart is empty, please add item to proceed to checkout")

        else:
            checkout = int(input('''Do you want to proceed to checkout?
                                1. Yes
                                2. No '''))
            if checkout == 1:
               checkout = input('''Please select how you would like to pay for your purchase: 
                                1. Gift Voucher
                                2. Credit / Debit Card
                                3. Paypal''')
            if checkout == 2:
               break

            else:
                 if checkout  == 1:
                    input("Please enter your gift voucher code")
                    print("Thank you")

                 elif checkout == 2:
                    input("Please enter your Credit / Debit card information")
                    print("Thank you")

                 elif checkout == 3:
                     input("vffsdfsdfsd")
                     print("TA")

                 else:
                     print("Please select a valid payment method")
                     break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using same variable `Do you want to proceed to checkout?` and `Please select how you would like to pay` variable try changing variable for `payment method` type as `payment_method`

```
 def checkout(self):
          while True:
            if not shopping_cart:
                print("Your cart is empty, please add item to proceed to checkout")
    
            else:
                checkout = int(input('''Do you want to proceed to checkout?
                                    1. Yes
                                    2. No '''))
                if checkout == 1:
                   payment_method = input('''Please select how you would like to pay for your purchase: 
                                    1. Gift Voucher
                                    2. Credit / Debit Card
                                    3. Paypal''')
                if checkout == 2:
                   break
    
                else:
                     if payment_method  == 1:
                        input("Please enter your gift voucher code")
                        print("Thank you")
    
                     elif payment_method == 2:
                        input("Please enter your Credit / Debit card information")
                        print("Thank you")
    
                     elif payment_method == 3:
                         input("vffsdfsdfsd")
                         print("TA")
    
                     else:
                         print("Please select a valid payment method")
                         break
```